# Как сделать чтобы кнопка перекрывала бордер родителя?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать:
через абсолютное позиционирование, задавая ширину 101% и сдвигать на 0.5% влево, но это не адаптивно получается. Как быть?

Comment: абсолют + right: -1px; left: -1px; bottom: -1px; и не ставить ширину

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev А почему не в ответ, а в комментарий? Стесняетесь? :)

Comment: @tutankhamun без фиддла или cниппета не уверен на 100%, предпочитаю в ответ только точные ответы ставить. А писать сниппет самому лень

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  max-width: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem 0rem 34px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.block span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  background: #f66001;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .65rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
    Цена составит
    <span>320р</span>
  </div>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">Заказать укладку</a>
</div>
```

P.S: *Возможно у Вас задан overflow: hidden; он и мешает.*

**Либо еще такой вариант:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.block span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 10rem;
  background: #f66001;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .65rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
    Цена составит
    <span>320р</span>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn">Заказать укладку</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Простой набросок:

```css
.block1 {
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  height: 100px;
}
.block2 {
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  width: 152px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  300 руб
  <div class="block2">
    Заказать
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, не надо править сообщения так, что результат работы кода меняется от ваших правок!

Comment: @Visman, и что же я такого исправила, что ответ изменился?!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, оригинальный код https://jsfiddle.net/Legionary/xrm9c1hz/1/ , ваш вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/xrm9c1hz/ Отображается совершенно по разному: у автора ответа он похож на то, что нужно автору вопроса, а то что написали вы - совершенно не похоже на то, что нужно вопрошающему.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо! Прошу прощения!

Answer (score 0):

То о чем Вы говорите в вопросе - это не адаптивность, это резиновость, если так можно выразиться. При адаптивности, блоки не будут уменьшаться в размерах, а будут перестраиваться на странице с учетом доступного пространства, поэтому вариант с position: absolute либо position: relative вам вполне подойдет.

Если же нужно будет уменьшить блоки в размерах, то потребуется использование медиа-запросов.

Вот набросал вам примерчик:

```css
.box {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">Цена составит</p>
  <p class="price">320 р</p>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Заказать укладку</a>
</div>
```

Думаю, что идея ясна.